# Error integrating Gazebo 1.9 with Ros Hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, ubuntu, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to wrap gazebo to interface with the the ROS. Followed the stepwise instruction in the gazebo page, everything goes fine but when I try to run the simulator it says could not connect to the master. when I run the gzserver in another terminal it works despite the error. Isnt gazebo supposed to run with only

```
$ rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

command?

```
saroj@saroj:~$ rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.

Msg Waiting for master.Error [parser_urdf.cc:2680] Unable to load file[/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so].

Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:289] Unable to read sdf file[/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so]

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost::lock_error
.............................
Error [ConnectionManager.cc:116] Failed to connect to master in 30 seconds.

/home/saroj/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gazebo: 25: kill: invalid signal number or name: SIGINT
```

Has anyone else faced similar problem??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77421/error-integrating-gazebo-1.9-with-ros-hydro/) by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved.. had to use $killall gzserver because it was still running the previous instance because of error while closing.

---

Originally posted by [espee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6531/espee/) with karma: 81 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1